# Javascript: Regex to convert a numbered list string to an array of items

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to convert a numbered list into an array of items. This is what I have so far:

```js
let input = `1. This is a text\n    where each item can span over multiple lines\n  1.1 this is another item\n 1.2another item\n  2. that I want to\n    extract each seperate\n    item from\n    3. How can I do that?`;

let regex = /(\d+\.\d+|\d+)\s(.*)/g;
let matches = input.match(regex);
console.log(matches);
```

This only produces the following output:

```js
"1.1 this is another item"
```

What I would like is something like this:

```js
"1. This is a text"
"1.1 this is another item"
"1.2another item"
...and so on
```

Why is it matching only one item out of this string? What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex does not foresee a dot after a number when there is no second number following it. It also requires a space after the number, but you have a case where there is no such space. So make it optional.

Also, use the `s` modified so `.` also matches newline cha

If a new item can start on the *same* line, you'll need a look-ahead to foresee where a match must end.

Correction:

```js
let input = `1. This is a text\n    where each item can span over multiple lines\n  1.1 this is another item\n 1.2another item\n  2. that I want to\n    extract each seperate\n    item from\n    3. How can I do that?`;

let regex = /(\d+\.\d*)\s?(.*?)(?=\d+\.|$)/gs;
let matches = input.match(regex);
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: Thank you! This works on this example, but when I try it on another string such as the [one here](https://jsfiddle.net/3yw8ms9f/3/), it returns a null or just the entire string.

Comment: OK, I see. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another option using a negated character class:

```
\b\d+\.\D*(?:\d(?!\.)[^.]*)*
```

**Explanation**

- `\b\d+\.\` A word boundary, match 1+ digits and a dot
- `\D*` Optionally match non digits
- `(?:\d(?!\.)[^.]*)*` Optionally match a digit asserting not a dot directly to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9QFjtZ/1)

```js
let input = `1. This is a text\n    where each item can span over multiple lines\n  1.1 this is another item\n 1.2another item\n  2. that I want to\n    extract each seperate\n    item from\n    3. How can I do that?`;

let regex = /\b\d+\.\D*(?:\d(?!\.)[^.]*)*/g;
let matches = input.match(regex);
console.log(matches);
```

If you want to keep the start of the string into account where the digits and the dot start, you can follow the match by asserting not a digit and dot pattern at the start of the string:

```
^[^\S\n]*\d+\..*(?:\n(?![^\S\n]*\d+\.).*)*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lNEJyl/1)

```js
let input = "1. This is a text with a number 1.2 and 3.\n    where each item can span over multiple lines\n  1.1 this is another item\n 1.2another item\n  2. that I want to\n    extract each seperate\n    item from\n    3. How can I do that?";

let regex = /^[^\S\n]*\d+\..*(?:\n(?![^\S\n]*\d+\.).*)*/gm;
let matches = input.match(regex).map(s => s.trim());
console.log(matches);
```